# Can I use multiple number of formset in a single form in django,if yes how?

Tags: python, django, forms, formset

I have to make a form in which more than one formset is used. please tell me if this is possible. if yes then how?

Answer (score 18):

You can add as many formsets in the form. Just create/init them in view and pass to template to render in the form.

Something like:

```
{{ formset1.management_form }}
{% for form in formset1 %}
    {{ form }}
{% endfor %}

{{ formset2.management_form }}
{% for form in formset2 %}
    {{ form }}
{% endfor %}
```

You are using multiple formsets in one view, you need to use prefix for the forms as explained here [Using more than one formset in a view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#using-more-than-one-formset-in-a-view)
In short:

```
article_formset = ArticleFormSet(prefix='articles')
book_formset = BookFormSet(prefix='books')
```

Comment: This does not work correctly. As the management form for both the formsets would be same, there is no way to distinguish between formset1.management_form and formset2.management_form in the template. Management form actually contains 3 hidden input field:<input type="hidden" name="form-TOTAL_FORMS" value="1" id="id_form-TOTAL_FORMS" /><input type="hidden" name="form-INITIAL_FORMS" value="0" id="id_form-INITIAL_FORMS" /><input type="hidden" name="form-MAX_NUM_FORMS" id="id_form-MAX_NUM_FORMS" /> and these are same for all formsets. I wonder why doesn't django distinguish between these.

Comment: @tejinderss, you need to use prefix while creating formsets in view, refer https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#using-more-than-one-formset-in-a-view

Comment: This answer does not include the case in which same model or form is about to use; for example if we want to use a formset of formset in a single view.

Answer (score 1):

When adding a prefix='article' We need to consider that the id of the formset will change and there are  other changes too like

```
<label for="id_form-0-title">Title:</label> 

<label for="id_article-0-title">Title:</label>
```